# Create keyvault secret - Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I want to create multiple secrets in keyvault. Assign dynamic values of Blobstorage account, Batch account.
I tried below code to create secrets:

```
Function CreateKeyvaultSecrets  
{  
 Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [string] $keyvaultName,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
         [string] $blobStorageAccountName,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
         [string] $batchaccountName,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3)]
         [string] $logRgName
    )

    #Get Storagekey        
    $blobStorageKeyObject = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $logRgName -AccountName $blobStorageAccountName)| Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq "key1"}
    $blobStorageKey = $blobStorageKeyObject.Value

    $blobStorageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=$blobStorageAccountName;AccountKey=$blobStorageKey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"


    #Create blobstorage key secret
    $blobSecretkey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $blobStorageKey -AsPlainText -Force

    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -Name 'blobstorageaccesskey' -SecretValue $blobSecretkey

    #Create blobstorage connectionstring key secret
    $blobconnectionstringSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $blobStorageConnectionString -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName -Name 'blobstorageconnectionstring' -SecretValue $blobconnectionstringSecret
    Write-host "Blob Storage Account connection string added to Keyvault secret"

    
}


CreateKeyvaultSecrets 'kvtevalmock' 'steval' 'abtaeval' 'rg-eval'
```

I am trying to execute above code from Azure DevOps Powershell task. Azure powershell version is 5.

Secrets are not getting creating. Below error is thrown:

```
WARNING: Upcoming breaking changes in the cmdlet 'Set-AzKeyVaultSecret' :

- The output type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.Models.PSKeyVaultSecret' is changing

- The following properties in the output type are being deprecated : 'SecretValueText'

- The change is expected to take effect from the version : '3.0.0'

Note : Go to https://aka.ms/azps-changewarnings for steps to suppress this breaking change warning, and other 
information on breaking changes in Azure PowerShell.
##[error]Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your script on my side, it works fine.

[image]

From the error message, looks your [`Az.KeyVault`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.KeyVault/3.4.0) powershell module version is too old, my version is `3.4.0`, try to update it with the command below.

```
Update-Module -Name Az.KeyVault -Force
```

After the update, close all the powershell sessions and open a new one to try again, it should work.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am trying to execute powershell commandlets using Azure powershell task(version 5) from Azure DevOPs. Script does not work and throws error as provided by me.

Comment: @Amruta I test it in the devops powershell task 5.*, it works fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhuf.png. Make sure you choose the Azure PowerShell Version with the latest installed version and does it work in local?